# How to organize a Shoes Ruby app?

Tags: ruby, shoes

can I have some examples of how you organize your Shoes apps? I mean, simply using a Shoes.app{} block and instance variables is clumsy.. I'd like to achieve a MVC like structure.. I'm used to it (from rails, FLEX frameworks and others..) and would like to recreate something similar..

Answer (score 2):

The way I usually manage this problem, is through the following separation:

- **Models** - you ordinary model code/business logic (ripe for testing!)
- **Tabs/Views** - separate views for different menu items embedded in the application

To achieve the latter I extracted a little slot handling library, which hasn't yet been extracted to its separate gem or even repository (waiting for shoes4 here).

The files needed are [here in my pomdoro tracker project](https://github.com/PragTob/pomodoro_tracker/tree/master/lib/pomodoro_tracker) - it's slot.rb, slot_manager.rb and dynamic_slot.rb - you can see them being put to use in the aforementioned project.

Basically the slot manager hides the old view and loads the new view upon request. This code was initially extracted from the hacketyhack tabs.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at some open-source shoes apps and see how the developers have organised them. A massive list of shoes products can be found at: http://the-shoebox.org/.

Comment: That is a dead link